# Intellij Idea не видит в Thymeleaf метод enum.values()

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

При создании выпадающих списков использую enum
и Idea не видит стандартный метод values() в документе Thymeleaf
В самом enum все видится 
[image: так в документе thymeleaf]

Пока что сделал костыль в виде обертки :
[image: костыль]

Но все же хочется узнать, можно ли использовать стандартные методы и не ловить warnings ??